# stacked generator

Tags: python, generator

In order to tokenize a file I have a generator that spits out the whitespaceseparated parts of the file, ignoring linebreaks.

```
def parts(filename):
  file = open(filename, 'r')
  for line in file:
    for part in line.split():
      yield part
```

Now, I'd like to write that as a generator comprehension - what didn't work is:

```
p = (part for part in line.split() for line in file)
```

or

```
p = (part for part in (line.split() for line in file))
```

The latter spits out the splitted lines instead of the parts of the splitted lines

Comment: I like the oxymoron "whitespaceseparated" )

Comment: No, the latter is a syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
p = (part for line in file for part in line.split())
```

The outermost for-loop in a generator expression is the left one.

Comment: +1, loops in a comprehension are written in the same order as normal ones

Comment: It also may help people to pad the generator expression out on different lines to show how the loops work.

Answer (score 1):

```
(word for line in input_file for word in line.split())
```

Comment: word is indead a better name for the variable